# Get product total sales per moth, with 0 in the gaps

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been stuck in a recent problem with a SQL Query. What I'm trying to archieve is to get each product in the store and show how many of them has been sold each month. However, sometimes there are some months where these products were not sold, which means they won't be displayed.

For instance, this is the result I'm getting right now

```
      Article   Month  Sold
      CN140027    6     312
      CN140027    7     293
      CN140027    12    122
      CN140186    1     10
      CN140186    4     2
```

While I want to get something more like this

```
      Article   Month  Sold
      CN140027    6     312
      CN140027    7     293
      CN140027    8     0
      CN140027    9     0
      CN140027    10    0
      CN140027    11    0
      CN140027    12    122
      CN140186    1     10
      CN140186    2     0
      CN140186    3     0
      CN140186    4     2
```

And here is the query I'm using at the moment

```
SELECT k.artikelnr, Months.datefield as `Months`, IFNULL(SUM(k.menge),0) as `Quantity`
FROM store_shop_korb as k LEFT OUTER JOIN office_calendar AS Months 
ON Months.datefield = month(k.date_insert)
WHERE k.date_insert BETWEEN "2014-12-01" AND "2015-12-31"
group by k.artikelnr, Months.datefield
```

What am I missing? Or what am I doing wrong? Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Additional information:

office_calendar is the calendar table. It only contains the months as registry, from 1 to 12.

Additionally, I'm taking the article/product ID from a table called 'store_shop_korb', which contains all the lines of a made order (so it contains the article ID, its price, the quantity for each order..)

Comment: Try RIGHT OUTER JOIN instead of LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: Yes, I've tried both Left, Right and Inner Joins. I still get the same result all the time

Comment: are those months with gaps actually represented in your calendar table? We need to see the data in your calendar table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
SELECT k.artikelnr, c.datefield AS `Month`, COALESCE(s.Quantity, 0) AS Sold
FROM (
    SELECT artikelnr
    FROM store_shop_korb
    GROUP BY artikelnr
) k
JOIN office_calendar c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT artikelnr, MONTH(date_insert) AS monthfield, SUM(menge) AS Quantity
    FROM store_shop_korb
    GROUP BY artikelnr, MONTH(date_insert)
) s ON k.artikelnr = s.artikelnr AND c.datefield = s.monthfield
ORDER BY k.artikelnr, c.datefield
```

If you have a table of articles, you can use it in the place of subquery k.  I'm basically normalizing on the fly.

Explanation:

There's basically 3 sets of data that get joined.  The first is a distinct set of articles (k), the second is a distinct set of months (c).  These two are joined without restriction, meaning you get the cartesian product (every article x every month).  This result is then left-joined to the sales per month (s) so that we don't lose 0 entries.

Comment: Do you think for the not matching months this query will fetch `x.artikelnr` (ie) `article`

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed. One last thing: would you be kind to explain me how does it work? Because I still don't get what's going on when there are more than two joins. Thank you very much, and also thanks everyone for the answer.

Comment: I've got an issue though: what if I need to take the sales for more than one year? For example, from January 2014 to June 2015.

Comment: 1.  You would need to use a calendar (c) that contains a list of the months you're interested (in this case, probably (year, month) pairs)
2.  Adjust the grouping in the sales per month (s) to group by year and month
3.  Adjust the join on s to join on year and month.
4.  Adjust the field selection and ordering to include year and month

Answer (score 0):

Add another where condition , i think it will solve your problem

```
SELECT k.artikelnr, Months.datefield as `Months`, IFNULL(SUM(k.menge),0) as `Quantity`
```

FROM store_shop_korb as k LEFT OUTER JOIN office_calendar AS Months 
ON Months.datefield = month(k.date_insert)
WHERE  IFNULL(SUM(k.menge),0)>0 AND k.date_insert BETWEEN "2014-12-01" AND "2015-12-31"
group by k.artikelnr, Months.datefield

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this in MSAccess and it seems to work OK

```
SELECT PRODUCT, CALENDAR.MONTH, A

FROM CALENDAR LEFT JOIN (

    SELECT PRODUCT, MONTH(SALEDTE) AS M, SUM(SALEAMOUNT) AS A
    FROM SALES 
    WHERE SALEDTE BETWEEN #1/1/2015# AND #12/31/2015#
    GROUP BY PRODUCT, MONTH(SALEDTE) ) AS X

ON X.M = CALENDAR.MONTH
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you already have a calender table then use this.

```
SELECT B.Article,
       A.Month,
       COALESCE(c.Sold, 0)
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT Months.datefield --Considering this as months feild
        FROM   office_calendar AS Months) A
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT article
                   FROM   Yourtable) B
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Yourtable C
                    ON a.month = c.Month
                       AND b.Article = c.Article
```

Else you need a `months` table. Try this.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT 1 AS month UNION
        SELECT 2 UNION
        SELECT 3 UNION
        SELECT 4 UNION
        SELECT 5 UNION
        SELECT 6 UNION
        SELECT 7 UNION
        SELECT 8 UNION
        SELECT 9 UNION
        SELECT 10 UNION
        SELECT 11 UNION
        SELECT 12) A
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT article
                   FROM   Yourtable) B
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Yourtable C
                    ON a.month = c.Month
                       AND b.Article = c.Article
```

Comment: op has already stated that a right and full join was tried ... how is your solution different?

Comment: Stop blindly commenting!. Check is it same as OP's `Left OUTER JOIN`